# Hide shipping option and show only store pickup based on cart attribute values

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Is there any way that we can hide the shipping option and only show the Store pickup option based on cart attributes?

I want to hide the shipping option when products are purchased through a wedding registry.
I have gone through Shopify functions! https://shopify.dev/.../delivery.../getting-started
but not sure if it's possible or not!

Answer (score 0):

There is no default functionality to enable this option. But there is not a big deal to develop a custom code that will show the Store pickup option for specified attributes/source of products in the cart.
Here you can get helpful information on [Shopify Shipping](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/shipping/shopify-shipping?utm_campaign=Guru%20Ask&utm_medium=forum&utm_source=social).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Shopify plus store, you could use the Scripts Editor app [like this example](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/examples/shipping-scripts#hide-rates-for-specific-products-in-certain-countries) if not using a Shopify plus store and you are able to use a server like node.js using the [Shopify admin api](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-07/resources/carrierservice) for carriers and based on conditions like line item properties, car notes, etc you could return the specific carriers for each order.